# How do I design a level detector when all commercial P/N cannot stand high voltage?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, simulation

I want to design a voltage detector for monitoring one power line. If the line has a higher voltage level than a reference a logic 3.3 signal is sent, if not, the opposite logic signal is sent. This is easy with a commercial comparator. The thing is that I could have 70V spikes on that line, so, I have two problems:

- There are no comparators which can be powered (I would need to power them with the same line, I cannot depend on another voltage value/line) with a line that can have 70V spikes.
- Comparators cannot stand possible spikes in the inputs that high.
  I want to monitor a 30V line, knowing is it is higher or not than 25V. I have thought about an optocoupler. Power problem would be solved and I would have to calculate the resistor in order not to burn the diode. But, simulating this, I cannot use it, because I wanted to detect certain level in the transient, but:
- For 25V, the BJT is already saturated, so, there is no threshold to set, it is 3.3V already (number 2 in the picture).
- The microcontroller would read a logic one according to the voltage that the MCU considers as a logic high value (around 0.8V) (number 1), so the GPIO would read a wrong value way before the input is 25V.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> There are no comparators which can be powered (I would need to power them with the same line, I cannot depend on another voltage value/line) with a line that can have 70V spikes.

So, you need, just as anyone else, a power supply, with overvoltage protection. Doesn't sound very unique a problem to me!

> Comparators cannot stand possible spikes in the inputs that high.

So your inputs need to be protected against *transient voltage spikes*.

That's sounds pretty easy – a large series resistor (doesn't hurt your sensing, because input impedance of a comparator should be very, very high) and a so-called TVS diode (better: a pair of antiparallel diodes) would solve that. Standard technique!

Especially standard because you'll want a voltage divider anyway to bring down your 30 V into the permissible input range of your comparator. So, the series resistor is already there – as half the voltage divider. Just put the TVS diode in parallel with the other half.

> I want to monitor a 30V line, knowing is it is higher or not than 25V. I have thought about an optocoupler.

Which helps you only a little, because you would just replace one spike-sensitive component with another one. Just that the input on the comparator needs nearly no current, which makes it easy to have large series resistors.

So, that's roughly what I'd have in mind:

[image: Overvoltage-protected comparator schematic]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a voltage divider on your "high voltage" signal to bring it bellow your voltage rail. Optionnaly, you can add a zener diode to clamp the voltage in case your input voltage is goes to high.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8GOw8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and R2 form a voltage divider, transforming Vin into a lower voltage V+= Vin*R2/(R1+R2). With the chosen values, V+=Vin/20, so if your maximum voltage for Vin is 30V, then V+ is at most 1.5V (so bellow your 3.3V supply rail).

If there is a risk of the worst case Vin being far above the threshold (for example the threshold is at 5V while the signal might be 50V), then adding a zenzer diode (D1) with a voltage around 3V will clamp V+ to this voltage. This way, you can go as high as you want on Vin, provided R1 can withstand the current (and voltage) and D1 can withstand the current.

So now, instead of having a high voltage Vin, you have a lower voltage V+ : you can then compare it easely with a fixed voltage (that you can generate from the 3.3V rail using the voltage divider R3-R4